# Bouncing Cube Program from The Office

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jframe, jpanel

I'm writing a program taken from the TV show, THE OFFICE, when they're sitting in the conference room and watching the bouncing DVD logo on the screen try to hit the corner. The square is supposed to change color when it hits an edge. 
However, I'm running into a few issues.

Issue one: The Square sometimes bounces off an edge. Other times it sinks, and I can't figure out why.

Issue two: I'm not sure how to change the color of the  square when it hits the edge.

Issue three: I'm trying to learn how to make a JFRAME fullscreen. And not just fullscreen on my screen but on anyone's.

THE CODE HAS BEEN POSTED TO AN ONLINE IDE FOR EASIER READING. That can be found [HERE](https://ideone.com/bBxMpb)

Otherwise if you're too busy for that link. Here it is posted below.

```
 import java.util.Random;
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;

 public class BouncingMischievousSquare extends JPanel implements ActionListener { 

private static final int SQUARE_SIZE = 40;
private static final int SPEED_OF_SQUARE = 6;
private int xPosit, yPosit;
private int xSpeed, ySpeed;

BouncingMischievousSquare(){
    //speed  direction
    xSpeed = SPEED_OF_SQUARE;
    ySpeed = -SPEED_OF_SQUARE;
    //a timer for repaint 
    //http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html
    Timer timer = new Timer(100, this);
    timer.start();
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    //Screensize
    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();
    xPosit += xSpeed;
    yPosit += ySpeed;
    //test xAxis
    if(xPosit < 0){
        xPosit = 0;
        xSpeed = SPEED_OF_SQUARE;
    }
    else if(xPosit > width - SQUARE_SIZE){ 
        xPosit = width - SQUARE_SIZE;
        xSpeed = -SPEED_OF_SQUARE;
    }
    if(yPosit < 0){
        yPosit = 0;
        ySpeed = SPEED_OF_SQUARE;
    }
       else if(yPosit > height - SQUARE_SIZE){ 
        xPosit = height - SQUARE_SIZE;
        xSpeed = -SPEED_OF_SQUARE;
       }
    //ask the computer gods to redraw the square
    repaint();
}
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g){       
     super.paintComponent(g);
     g.fillRect(xPosit, yPosit, SQUARE_SIZE, SQUARE_SIZE );
 }
 }
```

MAIN CLASS

```
 import javax.swing.*;



public class MischievousMain {
public static void main(String[] args) {
   JFrame frame = new JFrame("Bouncing Cube");
   frame.setSize(500, 500);
   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   // mischievous square input
   frame.add(new BouncingMischievousSquare());
   frame.setVisible(true);
}  



}
```

Anyways, Thanks for taking the time to read through my code. It's appreciated. I'm really interested in different ways to go about this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Issue one: The Square sometimes bounces off an edge. Other times it
>   sinks, and I can't figure out why.

You'll hate yourself for this, but

```
} else if (yPosit > height - SQUARE_SIZE) {
    xPosit = height - SQUARE_SIZE;
    xSpeed = -SPEED_OF_SQUARE;
}
```

Should be...

```
} else if (yPosit > height - SQUARE_SIZE) {
    yPosit = height - SQUARE_SIZE;
    ySpeed = -SPEED_OF_SQUARE;
}
```

You were using `xPosyit` and `xSpeed` instead of `yPosyit` and `ySpeed`...

> Issue two: I'm not sure how to change the color of the square when it
>   hits the edge.

Basically, whenever you detect a edge collision and change direction, simple change the panel's foreground color to something else...

This might require you to have a list of colors from which you can randomly pick or simply randomly generate the color

Then in your `paintComponent` method, simple use `g.setColor(getForeground())` before you fill the rect...

...ps...

To make life easier, you could just write a method that either generates a random color or sets the foreground to a random color, for example...

```
protected void randomiseColor() {

    int red = (int) (Math.round(Math.random() * 255));
    int green = (int) (Math.round(Math.random() * 255));
    int blue = (int) (Math.round(Math.random() * 255));

    setForeground(new Color(red, green, blue));

}
```

> Issue three: I'm trying to learn how to make a JFRAME fullscreen. And
>   not just fullscreen on my screen but on anyone's.

Take a look at [Full-Screen Exclusive Mode API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/)